# FileSystemWatcher odd behaviour

Tags: vb.net, winforms, filesystemwatcher

```
Imports System.IO

  Public Class Form1
   Dim watcher As New FileSystemWatcher()
   Dim FileChanged As Boolean
   Delegate Sub UpdateFileChangeDelegate()


   Private Sub Button_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button.Click
    watcher.Path = "C:\Demo Image Pool"
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite
    watcher.Filter = "DemoImage.raw"
    watcher.SynchronizingObject = Me
    AddHandler watcher.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    TextBoxMessage.Text = "Looking for file change"

    'The code below relates to Application
    Dim myProcess As New Process()
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "CaptureImage.exe"
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "60 500 8 100"
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True

    myProcess.Start()
    myProcess.WaitForExit(28000)
    myProcess.Close()

    While 1
        If FileChanged = True Then
            TextBoxMessage.Text = "Hello World"
            Exit While
        End If
    End While

 End Sub

 Private Shared Sub OnChanged(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    Form1.FileChanged = True
 End Sub

End Class
```

In the above code, the CaptureImage.exe captures a new image, "DemoImage.raw", at the FileWatcher location. I am changing the Boolean variable to true in the File Change event handler, however in the main thread, I am not able to get out of the loop. The reason being, I think, variable FileChanged being not changed or the change being not reflected. I would greatly appreciate if someone can point out where I have gone wrong. The form consists of simply a button and textbox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using a default instance and default instances are thread-specific.  As such, you're actually creating a new Form1 instance and setting its field rather than the Form1 instance that you have open.  No form should refer to its own default instance anyway, so that should be `Me.FileChanged` rather than `Form1.FileChanged`.

Apart from that, I really hope that is just some really dirty testing code because you have a busy wait loop there and that's about the worst code you can possibly write.

Comment: Since the event handler is shared sub, Me.FileChanged would give compile error. But you are right, it is dirty debugging code. However, as soon as I posted(which always happens with me) this question and I included Application.DoEvents() in while and it is able to break out of the while loop. I don't know whether that is the  "correct" answer but I waiting to see if there are any alternatives.

Comment: @DwightSchrute You need to accept his answer it is correct, this is a **very** common question/problem in VB, and is because vb.net is trying to be backward compatible with vb6. You should never refer to the default instance of a form, it is not visible and is not the code that you are running, you should be able to just say `FileChanged = True` since it is a class level variable. just noticed that you are using a `Shared` eventhandler what is your reasoning? If the method is Shared then the variable need to be shared also

Comment: I didn't notice that your event handler was `Shared`, mainly because it never occurred to me that it would be.  There is absolutely no reason to be using a `Shared` method to handle that event so get rid of the `Shared` keyword and then use `Me`.  I did wonder why referring to the default instance there didn't cause a compilation error so that explains it.